# I'm searching a motivational video about building an MVP in an agile approach on site at a shop

Tags: agile, motivation

I need to raise motivation of my team and would like to show them that it's possible to build an app from scratch even if requirements are not known in the beginning. The idea is to make them open to discuss with customers what their needs are and how frequently growing requirements can be a good thing when looking from customers perspective.

I have a specific video in mind but finding it seems impossible at the moment. In the video a team builds up their computers inside a shop and develops the app while requirements are taken from passing by customers building their MVP on the go.
Does someone know this or a similar video explaining the different phases from requirements to  wireframes and prototypes?

I want to explain, that not only code can be an outcome of a sprint but also design mockups or anything that helps business develop their product market fit.

Hope this post is appropriate at this spot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This site is focused on asking questions that allow for canonical answers. Search-type questions are generally not on topic on PMSE. Instead, it is better to focus on the *process* issue rather than asking questions for which a search engine or library would be a better resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! Asking the same question on LinkedIn helped to find people who might know it.

[Nordstrom Innovation Lab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NFH3VC6LNs)

They try to validate initial ideas in just one week by gathering real customer feedback.
So what do they do? They build up their machines in the store at Nordstrom in Seattle and ask customers passing by to test the iPad app which helps them compare different pairs of glasses. So they go from delivering a feature and getting feedback on it in just about 10 minutes, and make sure they only work on what is really important to the customers. It's all about value creation.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this video does a good job of explaining MVP:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P7nCmln7PM

[image]

This related article goes into more detail regarding MVPs. There are also great examples of how popular products started out as MVPs. This might be motivational to your team.

https://blog.crisp.se/2016/01/25/henrikkniberg/making-sense-of-mvp

Comment: This is a great example. I'll forward this to my team as well.